# searchbar on mvc view with javascript dinamics

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, searchbar

im trying to do a dinamic searchbar, so, i have a  element in my view, the data of the table is from the model of the view, and filled with a foreach loop.

now, my idea is, when i write on a text input element of the view, the model in the actioncontroller change, and when   returns to the js funtion the table load the new model and the view show the new data,
but isnt working.

i dont know how to tell to javascript, "hey, this is the new model, renew the view with the new model dinamicly"

this is my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<GestorBd.Models.Computadora>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ComputadoraGeneral";
}

<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Inventario" id="invbox" name="searchstringInv">
<br />
<div id="tabla">
    <table class="table table-hover" , id="tablaAFT">
        <tr>
            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AFT.NInventario)
            </th>
            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AFT.Receptor.AreaTrabajo)
            </th>

            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AFT.Receptor.Nombre)
            </th>

            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AFT.Estado)
            </th>


            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MarcaMotherboard)
            </th>



            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModeloMotherboard)
            </th>



            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModeloMicroprocesador)
            </th>



            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Generacion)</th>

            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MarcaChasis)</th>
            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CapacidadHD)</th>

            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TipoRAM)</th>
            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CantidadRAM)</th>
            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MarcaModeloTTarjetaVideo)</th>




        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AFT.NInventario)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AFT.Receptor.AreaTrabajo)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AFT.Receptor.Nombre)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AFT.Estado)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarcaMotherboard)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModeloMotherboard)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModeloMicroprocesador)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Generacion)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarcaChasis)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CapacidadHD)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoRAM)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CantidadRAM)
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarcaModeloTTarjetaVideo)
                </td>

                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">



                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Receptors", new {id =item.AFT.IdUbicacion})" title="Ubicación">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "AFTs", new {id =item.AFT.IdAft})" title="Más Detalles">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "AFTs", new {id =item.AFT.IdAft})" title="Editar">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("EditarDetallesTec", "AFTs", new {id =item.AFT.IdAft})" title="Editar Detalles Técnicos">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "AFTs", new {id =item.AFT.IdAft})" title="Borrar">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>



@section Scripts{

    <script>

       

      var error =  function earror() {
            alert("dio error");
        }

                $(function () {
                    $('#invbox').keyup(function () {
                        
                        var url = "@Url.Action("ComputadoraGeneral", "AFTs")";
                        var texto = $('#invbox').val();

                        var data = { searchstring: texto };

                        $.get(url, data).done(function (data) {

                            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = data;
                            alert("funciono");

                        }).fail(error);

            }

            );
        }
        );

    </script>







                                           }
```

this is the action on the controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ComputadoraGeneral(string searchstring)
        {
            //var modelo = db.AFTs.Join(db.Compputadoras, Af => Af.IdAft, com => com.IdComputadora,
            //    (Af, com) => new GeneralComputadora { aft = Af, Computadora = com });

            var modelo = db.Compputadoras.Include(m => m.AFT).Include(g => g.AFT.Receptor).ToList();


            if (searchstring != null)
            {

                modelo = db.Compputadoras.Include(m => m.AFT).Include(g => g.AFT.Receptor).Where(m => m.AFT.NInventario.Contains(searchstring)).ToList();
            }


           

            return View(modelo);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i realize that what im trying to do is unnecesary. i dont need to change the model. with all the data in the table, all that i need is search row by row with a for loop in the table and find what match with the string of the searchbar, the rows that dont match hidden it.

with this script it work for me,

```
<script>
            function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables
                var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue; var cont = 0;
      input = document.getElementById("invbox");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("tablaAFT");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = ""; cont++;
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
                }
                document.getElementById("spana").innerHTML = cont;

}
    </script>
```